# How to prevent RubyMine editor from modifying files

Tags: ruby, editor, rubymine

I'm working with RubyMine 2017.1.3 on Linux and it appears that RubyMine has modified one of my files to better fit its own idea of formatting. That causes distracting changes in the files since I have to inspect the differences (as detected by Git) and see if they are changes that I meant to make or what.

Is there a way to prevent RubyMine from automatically modifying a file? I searched through the settings but I wasn't able to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Ruby and change the settings to match your existing code (e.g. line spacing, tab width, etc).

Comment: Is there any way to tell RubyMine just to not change any formatting?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Commit message]

Make sure to pick the correct boxes when commiting changes.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Does this apply only to committing changes via Git or another revision control system?